# Get monthly archives for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I know this is a rather common topic, but I can't seem to resolve the issue I'm having. Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm spinning my wheels at this point.

Using Custom Post Type UI plugin, I've created some custom post types (I'll use 'blog' in this example). I've set has_archive => true, and I've also used a plugin called Custom Post Type Archives to get my pagination to work properly. So far, I have my permalinks, tags, categories and pagination working. However, the issue is when I try to use the wp_get_archives function. I understand this doesn't grab CPTs, so I've used the function that comes with the Custom Post Type Archives Plugin (wp_get_custom_post_archives). Depending on how I tweak the arguments, it spits out either a 404, or it loads the archives, but just displays every entry (not just those specific to the selected month). Ideally, I just want it to display monthly archives.

```
<?php wp_get_post_type_archives('blog');
```

Take a look  here:
http://www.metropoliscreative.com/coding/w/blog/

I've used this to register the post type and believe I've done it properly. Not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

```
register_post_type('blog', array(   
        'label' => 'Blog',
        'description' => 'Blog Entries',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'blog'),
        'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),
    'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),
    'labels' => array (
      'name' => 'Blog',
      'singular_name' => 'Blog',
      'menu_name' => 'Blog',
      'add_new' => 'Add Blog',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Blog',
      'edit' => 'Edit',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Blog',
      'new_item' => 'New Blog',
      'view' => 'View Blog',
      'view_item' => 'View Blog',
      'search_items' => 'Search Blog',
      'not_found' => 'No Blog Found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Blog Found in Trash',
      'parent' => 'Parent Blog',
    ),) );
```

Comment: Since has_archive was new in 3.1 (I think) it is very likely that one of those plugins might be not using it.

Comment: Wyck, I think you're right. It's not negatively affecting what I'm doing, though (I don't think). If I remove it, I can't get to blog/page/2 without a 404.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getarchives_where` hook of [wp_get_archives()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives) function

Add this function to your functions.php:

```
function Cpt_getarchives_where_filter( $where , $r ) {

  $post_type = 'blog';
  return str_replace( "post_type = 'post'" , "post_type = '$post_type'" , $where );
}
```

Then when you want your monthly archive put this:

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where' , 'Cpt_getarchives_where_filter' , 10 , 2 );
wp_get_archives();
remove_filter('getarchives_where' , 'Cpt_getarchives_where_filter' , 10 );
```

Comment: Hi Bainternet, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I'm still getting a 404.

Comment: I'm not seeing 404 at http://www.metropoliscreative.com/coding/w/blog/2011/03/ for example. and if you do still get 404 then it has noting to do with `wp_get_post_type_archive` or my answer.

Comment: My answer is to the question _Get monthly archives for custom post type?_

Comment: Your answer was giving me the 404. I've since gotten    wp_get_post_type_archive to not 404, however, it just grabs all entries, not ones from the respective month.

Comment: 404 means you are not getting to the page so the code i posted as nothing to do with it. also wp_get_post_type_archive can't generate 404 , so that's not the problem.

Comment: Right, but your code gave me a 404. Since then, I've implemented wp_get_post_type_archive and it doesn't give me 404s. Instead, it just gets all posts, not ones specific to the month. This method is the closest I've come to getting it to work. But getarchives_where does in fact give me a 404.

Comment: Once again the function i posted can't genreate a 404!!! its somerhint else. can you post the template code?

Comment: I copied the functions code verbatim... here is the template code: http://pastie.org/1769319

Here is where it's sitting... http://www.metropoliscreative.com/coding/w/blog/ 

The monthly archives 404. Thanks again for your time an help!

Comment: Well there is something wrong with your archives and its not related to post-types, if you go to my blog for example http://en.bainternet.info/ and append `index.php?year=2011` to the url you will get the yearly archive, in your site you get 404 that means the problem is with something else. try to dump_var $wp_query

Comment: Yeah... also didn't work. One thing that comes to mind, is I imported these posts from an old blog (they were regular posts) and I converted them to my new post type. Do you think that could have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yep i do. Try var_dump of $WP_Query to see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry... can you maybe walk me through this? I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Am I adding "var_dump" before my main post query, or is this something I add to where I'm calling my archives.

Comment: Oh! I think I may have found it. I changed my query_posts to get_posts, and it seems to work.... http://pastie.org/1772081 ... Maybe you can help me make sense of that? The different kinds of queries confuse me a bit.

Comment: It makes no sense! just glad you got it working.

Comment: Haha. Oh man. Well. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. :D

Comment: @Bainternet Following on from your solution is there a way to integrate the archives of a custom Post Type with that of the default Post Types? Ideally when I use the default Archive Widget (displaying month : year in a list) I want to include items from both Post Types.