# Extend the wp_get_archives output with '?post_type=foo'?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, customization, wp-get-archives

I've gotten my custom post types to display as it should in date based archives; the structure example.com/year/month/day (and above) works properly as long as it's extended with '?post_type=post_type_name'.

With [Bainternets](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13991/get-monthly-archives-for-custom-post-type/14006#14006) solution I've also gotten wp_get_archives to properly list archives based on whether or not they contain my CPT.

The problem is that wp_get_archives still returns the default archive permalinks, like this:

> example.com/year/month/day

but as I mentioned earlier, I need:

> example.com/year/month/day?post_type=post_type_name

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I found a plugin that does exactly what I need: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-archives Problem solved!

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and mark the question as _answered_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From comment:*

Use the plugin [Custom Post Type Archives](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-archives/). It is slightly more flexible than the argument `'has_archive' => TRUE` for `register_post_type()`.